# pycharm plugin is incompatible

Tags: pycharm

Due to accidentally installing lombok plugin to pycharm,
I didn't find the lombok plugin in preference. Every time I start pycharm, it will appear: Plugin Error: Plugin "Lombok Plugin" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).
How to remove it? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This type of unsuccessful installation seems to have no way to manage directly 
from:

*File → Settings → Plugins → Installed → Disable/Uninstall*

So I suggest you find the plugins and delete, see the below:

1. Find the directory plugins

   1.1 `Help` → `Edit custom VM Options...`

   1.2 right-click the tab, click `Show in explorer`

   1.3 Go to `plugins` directory
2. Find the `lombok-plugin-....jar` and remove then all done!

in my case is to delete the file `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2020.1\plugins\lombok-plugin-0.6.2-12.1.4.jar`